# Script not working when get value from a formula

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I found this script (below) and it works when simply typing in the number zero into Column G but it does not work when the result of column G comes from subtracting the values of column E and F. When the values become 0, it is left in the sheet "default". Any help would be appreciated. I have searched and find nothing about how this works when applied to the result of a formula. Thanks!

```js
function onEdit() {
  // moves a row from a sheet to another when a magic value is entered in a column
  // adjust the following variables to fit your needs
  // see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/ehoCZjFPBao/discussion

  var sheetNameToWatch = "default";

  var columnNumberToWatch = 7; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = 0;
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "toMoveTo";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
}
```

Comment: Add the formula and the values of the referred cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the script works as intended. I created a test spreadsheet with the script and did the following tests:

1. Enter random numbers in Column A — as expected nothing happened
2. Entered 0 in `Column A` — as expected nothing happened.
3. Entered random number in `Column G` (7) — nothing happened
4. Entered `0` in `Column G` — that row was moved to the other sheet
5. Entered `5` in `columns E` and `F` and `=E3-F3` which equals to `0` (in that order) — row was moved to the other sheet
6. Entered `5` in `column E` and `4` in `column F` and in `column G` I wrote the formula `=E3-F3` which resulted in `1`. After that, I changed `F4` to value `5` and formula recalculates to `0` — as expected, the row is **not** moved.

Please make sure that the formula actually returns a value of 0. It may be that your cell is formatted to write 0.1 as 0 and the formula returns a number `0 < n < 1` which would not be moved as it must be exactly 0 in order for this to work. If you wish to move values greater than 0 but less than 1, introduce a `Math.floor()` against the read value.

In test scenario 6 we have to note that the script does not account for changes made to any column other than `G` (column number `7`) because you are only watching `var range = sheet.getActiveCell();` so if you change anything other than the column where you are supposed to have `0` it will not do anything because of the following `if` statement part `range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch`

Comment: Thank you for your input. That makes sense. Do you have a suggestion that will simply "look for" the value and delete row if the value is present in the column regardless of whether it was typed in by the user or not?

Comment: @Derk yes, you simply get rid of the `sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch` part in `if` as that limits to only edits in that range and instead of `var range = sheet.getActiveCell();` you actually specify where you expect the value to be `0`. If this happens anywhere in column 7 then you may want to keep `getActiveCell()` but instead then do `var row = range.getRow()` and then `range = sheet.getRange(row, columnNumberToWatch)` That way whatever row you edit, you will check column 7 of that row